# Want to install Windows 7 in addition to Win32 and Ubuntu, how to proceed?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub

I have a 250GB hard drive with a 100GB Win32 XP Partition, 20GB Ubuntu 9.10 with Grub installed. I want to install Windows 7 'behind' those two.

How do I proceed so I will still be able to boot into Windows XP and less importantly into Ubuntu. I boot the Ubuntu partition via VirtualBox usually. Will Windows 7 overwrite Grub with its own bootloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very interesting thread https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

**This is an extract from another forum**

> 1. Obtain a copy of Windows7.
> 2. Partition your disk with gparted.
> 3. Install Windows7.
> 4. Re-install Grub.
> 5. Edit Grub to List Windows 7.
> 6. Have Fun.
>
>    ---
>
> **1.** Obtain a copy of windows 7.
>
> *You can also find a torrent of this but for legal reasons I cannot provide
>   a link. *
>
> **2.** Partition your disk
>
> **This does go wrong in some cases, if in doubt back up your valuable data.**
>
> Boot from a Ubuntu live cd or a
>   gparted live cd. Start up gparted, If
>   ubuntu is on the whole disk you need
>   to re-size it by at least 8 gb for
>   Windows 7. (Make sure windows 7 is on
>   the second partition to make it easier
>   for grub) You will be left with some
>   unallocated space on your hard disk if
>   you want you can partition it to NTFS
>   or you can do it later on the windows
>   install.
>
> **3.** Install Windows 7
>
> Follow the on screen instructions,
>   Select the un-partitioned space to
>   format and install windows on, or if
>   you already made it NTFS choose your
>   NTFS partition.
>
> **It will ask for a product key but you have 30 days to do that. Note:
>   Beta keys will work with the RC**
>
> **4.** Re-install GRUB
>
> Now you have windows 7 but it has
>   completely eaten your boot loader so
>   you need to re-install grub. Boot from
>   the ubuntu live cd and go to terminal.
>   Type in terminal:
>
> "sudo grub" "grub> find
>   /boot/grub/stage1"
>
> That should return your Ubuntu
>   partition in the form of (hdX,Y), use
>   that:
>
> grub> root (hdX,Y) grub> setup (hd0)
>   grub> quit
>
> (you don’t need to type the grub> bit)
>
> That has re-installed grub but you can
>   no longer see windows7
>
> **5.** Edit grub. Go to terminal from normal ubuntu and type :
>
> “sudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst”
>
> A large text file will open and at the
>   bottom leave a line and add this:
>
> title windows 7 beta (Loader) root
>   (hd0,1) savedefault makeactive
>   chainloader +1

Comment: This above mentioned method works for many people in that forum

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. Will read carefully and prepare.

Comment: If it works dont forget mark it as accepted , many people come here and as soon as they get an answer they leave the rest behind

Comment: Will do. Will probably only get to do it this weekend.

Comment: Will have to wait for another few days. Going on a short vacation for a few days, don't want to break my PC just before it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Windows 7 will overwrite Grub but it should recognize your XP partition.

see http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/reinstall-ubuntu-grub-bootloader-after-windows-wipes-it-out 
for restoring Grub which will see all OSes typically.